# Create array for each key in a Map<string, string>

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following interface

```
export class Items {
  items: Map<string, string>;
  createdBy: string;
  deliveredBy: string;
}
```

and I am getting my data the following day from the API call (Sorry I am not sure how to make a Stackblitz to represent the same data so pasting from console)

```
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1000", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData2000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1001", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData3000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1002", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData4000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOmeData1003", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData5000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1004", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData6000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1230", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData7000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1430", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData8000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOneData1340", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData9000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemONeData1210", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1000"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemONEData1430", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1100"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOnEData1334", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1200"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOnEData1555", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1300"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemOnEData9999", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1400"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemoNEData8888", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1500"}
Map(2) {"ItemOne" => "ItemONeData1550", "ItemTwo" => "ItemTwoData1600"}
```

I want to create and array for EACH key in a Map<string, string>.

My logic :

```
if(key) <-- to check for duplicate keys
  push(values) <-- push each key value to create an array
```

code:

```
myArr = [];
this.service
  .getItems(itemId)
  .pipe()
  .subscribe((val) => {
    const allData = this.val;
    allData.map((eachItem) => {
      eachItem.items.forEach((value, key) => {
        if(key){
            myArr.push(value)
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

}

This leads to creating array for each key value but does not create a one array for EACH key. Is there an efficient way to create arrays ?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build a single new map keyed by the keys in the maps in the `items` property of the objects in the array you get from your service, where the value for each key is an array of the values in those maps.

If so, nested loops is a straightforward way to do it:

```
const result = new Map();
for (const {items} of arrayFromService) {
    for (const [key, value] of items) {
        const arr = result.get(key);
        if (arr) {
            arr.push(value);
        } else {
            result.set(key, [value]);
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example *(you might want to look in the real browser console rather than the in-snippet one, because the in-snippet one doesn't show `Map` instances in a useful way [as of this writing])*:

```js
const arrayFromService = [
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1000"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData2000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1001"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData3000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1002"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData4000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOmeData1003"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData5000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1004"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData6000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1230"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData7000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1430"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData8000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOneData1340"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData9000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemONeData1210"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1000"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemONEData1430"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1100"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOnEData1334"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1200"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOnEData1555"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1300"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemOnEData9999"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1400"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemoNEData8888"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1500"]])},
    {items: new Map([["ItemOne", "ItemONeData1550"], ["ItemTwo", "ItemTwoData1600"]])},
];
const result = new Map();
for (const {items} of arrayFromService) {
    for (const [key, value] of items) {
        const arr = result.get(key);
        if (arr) {
            arr.push(value);
        } else {
            result.set(key, [value]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

The resulting array has `ItemOne` with the value:

```
["ItemOneData1000", " ItemOneData1001", " ItemOneData1002", " ItemOmeData1003", " ItemOneData1004", " ItemOneData1230", " ItemOneData1430", " ItemOneData1340", " ItemONeData1210", " ItemONEData1430", " ItemOnEData1334", " ItemOnEData1555", " ItemOnEData9999", " ItemoNEData8888", " ItemONeData1550"]
```

and `itemTwo` with the value:

```
["ItemTwoData2000", " ItemTwoData3000", " ItemTwoData4000", " ItemTwoData5000", " ItemTwoData6000", " ItemTwoData7000", " ItemTwoData8000", " ItemTwoData9000", " ItemTwoData1000", " ItemTwoData1100", " ItemTwoData1200", " ItemTwoData1300", " ItemTwoData1400", " ItemTwoData1500", " ItemTwoData1600"]
```

Comment: Hi T.J, Thank you so much for the code. Just one confusion, why is `const arr = result.get(key);` not undefined since the result map does not have keys inside of it currently.

Also, when I run the code snipped, it seems to be empty

Comment: @JeffBenister - Glad if that helps! `arr` is `undefined` the first time each key is encountered. That's what the `if (arr)` test is for -- if we've seen the key before, `arr` will be an array, which is truthy, so we go into the `if` block; if we haven't seen the key before, `arr` will be `undefined` and we'll go into the `else`.

Comment: For anyone confused about why `{}` shows up in the StackSnippets console, it is because the console is not able to show the structure of the Map object.

Comment: I understand, sorry I made a mistake when I copied the code and was running an into issue. Thank you again.